# Error: Unknown column 'x' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm having some trouble inputting some data into a table.

I'm retrieving some values from a form and inputting them to a table, but this error shows up every time:

> Error: Unknown column 'planner_id' in 'field list'

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include 'conexion_data.php';
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

    $teacherid = $_POST["teacherid"];
    $plannerid = $_POST["plannerid"];
    $yeargroup = $_POST["yeargroup"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $planner_event = htmlspecialchars($_POST["event_comment"]);
    $event_date = $_POST["event_date"];
echo "$teacherid $plannerid $yeargroup  $planner_event $event_date <br/><br />";


    if (empty($event_date) or empty($planner_event)) {
        echo "One of the fields was left blank! <br />";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO subject_directorio (planner_id, teacher_id, subject, yeargroup, date, comment ) VALUES ('$plannerid', '$teacherid', '$subject', '$yeargroup', '$event_date', '$planner_event')";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        } else {
        /* header('Location: user_area.php'); */
        echo "Data was inputed to DB";
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
     } 

?>
```

Comment: What is the table structure?

Comment: It's clear that in your mysql table you don't have a field called "planner_id". Use phpmyadmin for example to check the exact name of the fields

Comment: wiiii sql injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

## Database

You are using wrong way how to connect to database and fetch its data.
Because you database may be hacked using [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
The right way how to do this is:

### Using PDO

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
```

For error catching:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

And data fetching:

```
$id = 5;
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

### Using Mysqli

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

#### And your problem

I think problem is in your query and binding params to it.So try to use proper way as I shown you, and then show us results.
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca288/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

It's very straight

while you are getting this type error :{Error: Unknown column 'planner_id' in 'field list'}

Troubleshoot first step will be Just Describe The Table [subject_directorio]

Desc  subject_directorio and check planner_id is exist or not. According to to the error

subject_directorio not holding any column called as planner_id

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It's self explanatory that your table doesn't have a column `planner_id`. Even if you see that it has, you may have trialing spaces before or after `planner_id` in the column name. Check carefully.